Welcher dieser Sätze ist besser?
"Ich bin ein Schüler. Ich arbeite nicht, aber meine Arbeitszeiten und -plätze sind sehr ähnlich …"
"…, wie eines Arbeiters."
oder
"..., wie die eines Arbeiters."
Meine Frage ist: Welcher dieser Sätze ist grammatikalisch besser?

Die erste Variante ist falsch (wir haben nur einen Genitiv, aber kein Nomen oder Pronomen, auf das sich der Genitiv bezieht). Die zweite ist grammatikalisch richtig. Eine richtige Form ist besser als eine falsche. Also ist der zweite Satz besser.

Logik
Bevor ich auf die Grammatik eingehe, möchte ich einen auffälligen logischen Fehler ansprechen: Arbeitszeiten kann nur jemand haben, der arbeitet. Du kannst nicht zuerst ausdrücklich klarmachen, dass du gar nicht arbeitest, und dann sofort anschließend behaupten, dass du Arbeitszeiten hast, noch dazu im selben Satz. Das ist ein logischer Widerspruch. Wer nicht arbeitet, hat keine Arbeitszeiten.
Man kann die Tätigkeit einer Schülerin oder eines Schülers aber durchaus auch als Arbeit bezeichnen. Das wird auch häufig gemacht und ist nicht ungewöhnlich. Daher ist es grundsätzlich auch zulässig, bei Schülern von einem Arbeitsplatz zu sprechen (dem Platz, an dem man die Hausübungen schreibt), und natürlich auch von Arbeitszeiten. Aber wenn man ausdrücklich sagt, dass man nicht arbeitet, kann man nicht im selben Atemzug behaupten, Arbeitszeiten zu haben.
Du must dich entscheiden: Entweder betrachtest du die Tätigkeit von Schülern als Arbeit, dann arbeiten sie und dann haben sie auch einen Arbeitsplatz. Oder du behauptest, dass Schüler nicht arbeiten, dann ist ihre Tätigkeit aber keine Arbeit und daher können sie in dieser Sichtweise auch keinen Arbeitsplatz haben.

Grammatik
Artikel bei Gleichsetzungen


Ich bin ein Schüler.
Ich bin Schüler.


Der Satz 1 ist nicht ganz falsch, aber besser ist die Version 2 ohne Artikel. Denn wenn Gruppenzugehörigkeiten als Gleichsetzungsnominativ verwendet werden, lässt man den Artikel weg:

Maria ist Diabetikerin. Jochen ist Zahnarzt. Susanne ist Katholikin. Charles ist Brite. Donald ist Republikaner.

(Wer »Ich bin ein Berliner« sagt, behauptet streng genommen nicht, zu der Gruppe von Menschen zu gehören, deren Heimat die Stadt Berlin ist, sondern er behauptet eine mit Pflaumenmus gefüllte süße Backware aus Hefeteig zu sein.)
Vergleichssätze


Mein Fahrrad sieht gleich aus wie deines.
Mein Hemd sieht anders aus als deines.
Der Vortrag war so, wie ich das erwartet habe.
Guter Schlaf ist wichtiger, als viele denken.


Komma
In den Sätzen 1 und 2 wird ein Ding (Fahrrad, Hemd) mit einem anderem Ding (deines) verglichen. Nach wie oder als steht in diesem Fall nur eine Wortgruppe ohne Verb. Aber wenn da kein Verb vorhanden ist, ist das kein Nebensatz und dann darf vor wie oder als kein Komma stehen.
Wenn jedoch ein Verb oder mehrere Verben in dem Teil enthalten sind, der von wie oder als eingeleitet wird (erwartet habe; denken), so wie das in den Beispielen 3 und 4 der Fall ist, dann ist dieser Teil ein Nebensatz, der vom Hauptsatz durch ein Komma zu trennen ist.
Gleichheit
Gleichheit im grammatischen Sinn bedeutet: Gleichheit, Ähnlichkeit oder verneinte Gleichheit. In diesem Fall ist das Wort wie zu verwenden, und davor muss irgendwo das Wort »so« oder »gleich« stehen:

Mein Fahrrad sieht gleich aus wie deines.
Der Vortrag war so, wie ich das erwartet habe.
Ich schlafe nicht so lange wie meine Schwester.
Meine Arbeitszeiten sind so ähnlich wie die eines Arbeiters.

Ungleichheit
Ungleichheit im grammatischen Sinn liegt immer dann vor, wenn ein Adjektiv im Komparativ (in der ersten Steigerungsstufe) verwendet wird, oder wenn das Wort »anders« vorhanden ist. Wenn das der Fall ist, ist das Wort »als« zu verwenden. Eventuell vorhandene Verneinungen, die dazu führen, dass der Satz in seiner Bedeutung eine Gleichheit ausdrückt, haben darauf keinen Einfluss:

Mein Hemd sieht anders aus als deines.
Guter Schlaf ist wichtiger, als viele denken.
Sebastian schläft nicht länger als seine Schwester.
Ich arbeite weder länger noch kürzer als Erich.

Von deinen Vorschlägen ist daher leider keiner richtig. Die Wahl von »wie« ist zwar korrekt, weil es hier grammatisch um eine Gleichheit geht, aber nachdem in dem Teil nach »wie« kein Verb vorkommt, ist dieser Teil kein Nebensatz und daher darf vor »wie« kein Komma stehen.
Schwerwiegender ist aber, dass in dem Teil davor kein »so« steht. Richtig wäre diese Variante:

Meine Arbeitszeiten sind so ähnlich wie die eines Arbeiters.

Warum ist »... wie eines Arbeiters« falsch?
In dem Fall, in dem kein Komma zu setzen ist, liegt grammatisch eine Gleichsetzung mit dem Subjekt des Hauptsatzes vor. Das Ding, das nach dem Wort »wie« steht, wird dem Subjekt gleichgesetzt. Das Subjekt steht aber immer im Nominativ, daher muss der Vergleichsbegriff auch im Nominativ stehen. Und natürlich kann man nur vergleichbare Dinge miteinander vergleichen.

Zulässig: Vergleich von Personen (Schüler - Arbeiter)

Ein Schüler arbeitet so lange wie ein Arbeiter.


Zulässig: Vergleich von Zeiten (Lernzeit - Arbeitszeit)

Meine Lernzeit ist gleich lange wie deine Arbeitszeit.


Falsch: Vergleich von unterschiedlichen Qualitäten (Person - Zeit)


Meine Arbeitszeit ist wie ein Arbeiter.
Meine Arbeitszeit ist wie eines Arbeiters.




Der Satz 1 (... wie ein Arbeiter) ist zwar grammatisch richtig, aber semantisch falsch. Der Satz 2 (... wie eines Arbeiters) ist zusätzlich auch grammatisch falsch, denn die Wortgruppe »eines Arbeiters« steht im Genitiv, nach »wie« muss aber etwas im Nominativ stehen.
Warum ist »... wie die eines Arbeiters« richtig?
Die Phrase »die eines Arbeiters« steht als Ganzes im Nominativ und kann daher in einem Vergleich nach »wie« oder »als« stehen. Sie besteht aus zwei Teilen:

die
Das ist ein Demonstrativpronomen, das auf das Wort »Arbeitszeit« im Hauptsatz verweist. Es funktioniert also so, als ob anstelle dieses Demonstrativpronomens »die« dort die Wortgruppe »die Arbeitszeit« stünde. (Beachte, dass das Wort »die« in »die Arbeitszeit« kein Pronomen sondern ein Artikel ist.)

eines Arbeiters
Das ist ein Possessivattribut des Kerns der Phrase, und der Kern ist das zuvor erwähnte Demonstrativpronomen »die«. Possessivattribute sind im Deutschen entweder Präpositionalphrasen (»von einem Arbeiter«) oder eben Nominalphrasen im Genitiv (»eines Arbeiters«). Dass das Attribut im Genitiv steht, hat aber keinen Einfluss auf den grammatischen Fall der Wortgruppe, in der dieses Attribut enthalten ist. Der Teil »eines Arbeiters« ist zwar im Genitiv, aber die Gruppe »die eines Arbeiters« steht als Ganzes im Nominativ.


Eine andere Verwendungsart von ähnlich
In allen oben genannten Beispielen wurde das Wort ähnlich wie ein gewöhnliches Adjektiv verwendet. Hier sind weitere Beispiele für diese Verwendungsart:

Hafermilch schmeckt fast so ähnlich wie Kuhmilch.
Lisa und Laura sind einander ähnlicher als Daniel und Lukas.

Das Adjektiv ähnlich hat aber die Besonderheit, dass es auch wie eine Präposition verwendet werden kann. Es hat dann die grammatikalischen Eigenschaften eines Adjektivs und einer Präposition. Als Präposition verlangt dieses Wort den Dativ:

hinter dem Dativ: Herr Schmidt sieht dem Direktor ähnlich
vor dem Dativ: Eine Schüssel ist ein Behälter, ähnlich einer Schale, in die man etwas hineinlegen kann.

Du könntest deinen Satz so umbauen, dass du das Wort ähnlich als Präpositions-Adjektiv verwendest, dann musst du aber das Vergleichsobjekt in den Dativ stellen:

Meine Arbeitszeiten sind denen eines Arbeiters ähnlich.
Meine Arbeitszeiten sind ähnlich denen eines Arbeiters.

Weil das Wort »ähnlich« aber auch bei Verwendung als Präposition weiterhin ein Adjektiv ist, kannst du sogar das Wort »sehr« vor »ähnlich« stellen. Das geht mit echten Präpositionen nicht:

Meine Arbeitszeiten sind denen eines Arbeiters sehr ähnlich.
Meine Arbeitszeiten sind sehr ähnlich denen eines Arbeiters.

